# Java font compatibility

Tags: java, fonts, compatibility

Are logical fonts in Java (Dialog, DialogInput, Monospaced, etc.) compatible with Windows *and* Macintosh computers? If not, are there any fonts common with both Windows and Macintosh computers?

Comment: Pretty sure it uses fonts from the OS

Comment: Yes.  The logical fonts are, in fact, the only fonts guaranteed to be available on every (non-headless) platform.  That said, most user interfaces look and behave better if they are allowed to use their default fonts, as they will be consistent with the platform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Logical fonts are the five font families defined by the Java platform which must be supported by any Java runtime environment: Serif, SansSerif, Monospaced, Dialog, and DialogInput.

These logical fonts are not actual font libraries. Instead, the logical font names are mapped to physical fonts by the Java runtime environment. It also depends on the Locale.
It is assumed that all the OSs support a different set of fonts, Swing implementors decided to ensure at least these five fonts were supported everywhere.

They will be automatically mapped onto the most suitable font available at a given platform. Have a look at `jre/lib/fontconfig.properties.src` for details. Will there be common Fonts ? we can not be very sure as the platform specific fonts keep changing on OS revisions ( ex: windows 7/8 and OS X yosemite, Ubuntu etc). As a fall back some fonts are provided with the JRE - take a look at the folder under `jre/lib/fonts`.

Finally have a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/intl/fontconfig.html further details on this.